# Where is the documentation for BizTalk SendPort filters?

Tags: biztalk

I'm talking about this list. I can't find the documentation online. Is it available anywhere?

[image]

Here's a fine example, how would I fill this out if I wanted to use it? That's why I need documentation.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

1. Each item in that list is defined in a Property Schema that defines the type and hence what the value type in the filter should be. By adding new property schemas, there will be more items in the list.  So there won't be any definitive documentation for all of them.
2. Filters will mostly only work on Message Context Properties that are Promoted.

**Long explanation:**

This is the documentation [Setting Filter Expressions on Send Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/accelerator-hl7/setting-filter-expressions-on-send-ports), but it is very bare bones and just tells you how to set a filter.  What you need refer to for out of the box is [Message Context Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/technical-reference/message-context-properties1) e.g. [File Adapter Property Schema and Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/file-adapter-property-schema-and-properties)

But what you need to know is that each item in that list is associated with a Property Schema.  If you add more property schemas, those properties will also show in that list, so it is not a static list, but a dynamically generated one.  Adding some adapters will add more context properties.

If you look at the context properties for a message from a file receive location you can see the FileCreationTime property there and the value, if it is promoted or not (Type), and the Namespace of the Property Schema it is associated with.

e.g.

[image: Context Properties]

> Name: FileCreationTime
> Value: 19/05/2022 9:59:23 p.m.
> Type: Not Promoted
> Namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties

Also if you set a value to that filter and try and Enlist it and it is not the right type you get the following error.

[image: The expected type is a datetime]

You can see the type in the Property Schema
[image: Property Schema]

The FileCreationTime is not a Promoted Property, which generally means you generally can't subscribe to it, however there are some exceptions to this, but this is not one of them.

When I changed the rule to > and the value to `19/05/2022 9:59:23 p.m.`, the send port Enlisted, but did not subscribe to a message.

Below are the properties that are Promoted from a file receive by default

[image: Promoted properties]

InboundTransportLocation http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties

ReceivePortID   http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties

ReceivePortName http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties

InboundTransportType    FILE    Promoted    http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties

MessageType Transaction Promoted    http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties

Note: MessageType will only be present if you've disassembled a message.

You either need to use the properties that are promoted, or to promote the property you do want, or have logic in either an Orchestration or Pipeline Component that inspects that context properties and then sets promoted properties so that you can route the message.

For example I used the [BRE Pipeline Framework](https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework) to Promote the FileCreationTime property, and then the Filter does work.
[image: BRE Rule]